# How to add custom button and new features in TinyMCE in wordpress3.3

Tags: php, tinymce, wordpress

Note my wordpress version is 3.3.1

some hooks and function is not the same anymore, and the info on wordpress.org is not actually helping.

all I want to do is adding and customize the default behavior about, so any post to provide?

Comment: The question should moved to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Though I have to think that this question needs to be significantly improved before [wordpress.se] could help. What specifically changed? What did you have customized before that doesn't work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link on how to add a button: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.addButton

All you need to so is to adjust your wordpress settings regarding the tinymce init.